# Array of functions returning bool

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I have these boolean functions that I am writing individually and I was thinking to create an array and then use a loop to go over each of them. Below are individual functions that I would like to place in the array.

```
bool A(void);
bool E(void);
bool O(void);
bool P(void);
bool U(void);
bool I(void);
bool C(void);
bool L(void);
bool D(void);
```

Can I do this?

Comment: You mean an array of functions? Or an array of `bool`s?

Comment: arry of functions that are of type boolean

Comment: It would have to be an array of function _pointers_ -- are you comfortable with those?

Comment: @Beta i have tried pointers and that wouldn't work

Comment: @JonAbraham You can't have an array of "functions" in c++, you can use `std::function` or use function pointers.  so, you could have an array of `bool (*)(void)` if you wanted, but not of `bool(void)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have an array of `std::function`s (which is a generalized function pointer). Sample program:

```
#include <array>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

typedef bool Func(void);

Func A,E,O,P,U,I,C,L,D;

int main()
{
    std::array<std::function<Func>, 9> arr = { A,E,O,P,U,I,C,L,D };

    for ( auto&& f: arr )
        std::cout << f() << '\n';
}
```

You will need to provide bodies for all of those functions of course.

Prior to C++11 the code would have been:

```
Func *arr[] = { A,E,O,P,U,I,C,L,D };

for (size_t i = 0; i != sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]; ++i)
    std::cout << arr[i]() << '\n';
```

Using modern C++ code gives you more safety and flexibility, so it is to be preferred if you have a modern compiler available.

Comment: I am new to c++ can u tell me what does this line do ? std::array<std::function<bool(void)>, 9> arr = { A,E,O,P,U,I,C,L,D };

Comment: Make an `array` that contains `function` things that take no arguments and return `bool`. Default it to 9 items. Initialize it with `A,E,O,P,U,I,C,L,D`.

Comment: @JonAbraham `std::array<Type, Number>` means an array of Number items of type Type.   `std::function<bool(void)>` means a reference to a function which returns bool and has no parameters.

Comment: @RyanHaining yeah I was just thinking about that

Comment: @JonAbraham you could create an array of ints by saying `std::array<int, 5> arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`  the syntax for making an array of functions is going to be more complex

Comment: @RyanHaining I need a boolean array i am heading to what Matt has showed it looks intersting but on the second code that he has showed he is using pointers but i also need a boolean type of function.

Comment: it's an array of pointers to functions

Comment: @JonAbraham you seem mixed up between functions and return types. You are talking about functions which return boolean ,  not booleans by themself

Comment: Also worth mentioning (I think) that an array (either kind) of function pointers in C++11 could be `constexpr`

Comment: @MattMcNabb yes u read me right i was wrong

Comment: `Func` is an alias I have made for *function returning bool and taking no parameters* . It makes the code easier to read. Otherwise the pre-C++11 code would be `bool (*arr[])(void) = { A,E,O,P,U,I,C,L,D };` which is getting messy

Comment: @MattMcNabb u nailed it ,query solved ! Thank you Sir.

Comment: @MattMcNabb While executing a for loop arr[i] is not printing A,E,O,P,U,I,C,L,D. It just prints 1 ? So to troubleshoot i tried to cout<<*a and it gave me 1. I am aiming for A,E,O,P,U,I,C,L,D

Comment: @JonAbraham boolean value means it can either be `true` or `false`.  This means you can only ever print 2 things in response to calling these functions. (By default it is `1` for `true` and `0` for `false`).  Maybe you want your functions to return `char` instead of `bool`?

Comment: I assume you're aware you could just have an array of `char` without having any functions of course

Comment: @MattMcNabb yes you are right 1 or 0 is true or false (how can i forget that !) so that means something is wrong with my program . I may have to revise my program again !